# MySQL query with duplicate key?

Tags: mysql

First time I am trying `duplicate key` to have insert and update in one query. What's wrong with my query?

```
INSERT INTO tabletest(batchID, purchaseID) 
VALUES (553155, 892) ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE purchaseID = VALUES(purchaseID)
```

I'd like to insert or update if a batchID for a unique purchaseID exists. In the table purchaseID is UNIQUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `purchaseID` is the column with the `UNIQUE` constraint, then you should update only `batchID`:

```
INSERT INTO tabletest (batchID, purchaseID) 
  VALUES (553155, 892) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  batchID = VALUES(batchID)
```

Comment: tx ypercube, totally overlooked i wasn't using batchID but purchaseID.